# How assign Activity in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have ActionBar with 3 tabs. Each tab has a Fragmemt. How can I assign each tab an activity (each fragment has a button, how to assign Event on that button)?

```
public class TMABActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("MyBooks")
            .setTabListener(
                    new MyTabListener<NewsFragment>(this, "1",
                            NewsFragment.class, this));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("News")
            .setTabListener(
                    new MyTabListener<MyBooksFragment>(this, "2",
                            MyBooksFragment.class, this));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("Account")
            .setTabListener(
                    new MyTabListener<AccountFragment>(this, "3",
                            AccountFragment.class, this));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to attach any Activity to your fragments. An instance of Activity is automatically created for each fragment.

To add a listener, for example, on a button of each Fragment, you can override the method

```
void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

and get a reference to the Button with

```
Button button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.example_button);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragments do not need explicit activity assignment.